# How to detect when Firefox has finished loading a page using Python?

Tags: python, firefox, automation

Is it possible to use Python to detect when a web page has finished loading in the Firefox browser? I'm trying to automate some browser tasks using Python and this is the major stumbling block for me.  Note that this is for small-scale personal use, not a server farm or anything like that. The Firefox browser is in an open window, so I can see what it is doing.

BTW, I'm using Python version 2.6 on a Windows XP PC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't. Python doesn't run in the browser..

Answer (score 1):

1. [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) which can execute your scripts.
2. [PythonExt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7620/) python extension for mozilla.

   Either of these should work.

Comment: selenium seems gigantic for such a small job. PythonExt might be workable provided that the interpreter that runs inside the browser can communicate with the external interpreter that is automating the Firefox application.